# Will other rule results impact the correctness of the policy?

Tags: open-policy-agent

I am working on a rego policy that has multiple conditions. Each condition needs to make a call to the same endpoint of a REST api.

I have managed to retain the result of the service call as a result of another rule.

The result of the Evaluate Package command (VS Code with OPA extension) on the policy looks like this now:

> [   [
> {
> "allow": false,
> "someProp": [
> "N/A"
> ]
> }   ] ]

Will this affect the correctness of the policy once it gets deployed to the server?

**EDIT**

Until my changes, the policy only returned *allow*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "evaluate package" feature of the VS Code plugin does pretty much just that :) i.e. it evaluates the whole package including all rules. You'll see the same default behavior in the [Rego Playground](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/), since it's a pretty good way of learning what's going on to see what all rules evaluate to.

When running OPA as a server (or by all means, `opa eval`), you'll commonly query only the specific rule you're interested in, so if in your case you had defined your policy in a package called `mypolicy` a request to the OPA REST API might be sent to the `/v1/data/mypolicy/allow` endpoint to evaluate only the `allow` rule rathe than the whole package (which could be queried at `/v1/data/mypolicy`.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I have one more question, is there a security risk in my approach?

Comment: Not really. You'd normally deploy OPA exposed only on the localhost interface, so as long as you trust your client you're good. If you don't, OPA can be configured to require authentication/authorization, and limit what paths are open for queries.